# Facebook Opengraph help required

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am a little confused about open graph I just want my pages to display the correct data when liked or shared. I used the following

```
  <meta name="title" content="<%= MY PAGE %>" />
  <meta name="description" content="DESC" />
  <link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href=""/>
```

However when you use the send button it does not show the image in the popup.

So I added all the open graph tags. Which worked well. However it started generating facebook pages for each page (I dont want this to happen really). Also when you used the share button it tried to send the URL of the facebook object not my app page. Is this normal behavior.

I dont think I really understand open graph even after reading all the documentation. Can anyone explain whats going on, what the minimum amount I need to add to the page to get the like button and send button working is and what the deal is with these autogenerated pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I added all the open graph tags. Which worked well. However it started generating facebook pages for each page

No one sees these pages. I think (assume) you are referring to admin pages for objects liked outside of Facebook.

> Also when you used the share button it tried to send the URL of the facebook object not my app page. Is this normal behavior.

It will send the current page the code is on, if the current page is a Facebook object then that's what it will send.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

in the top

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID">
<meta property="og:url" content="URL_OF_CURRENT_PAGE">
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE">
<meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION">
<meta property="og:image" content"URL_TO_IMAGE">
```

Comment: OK this is what I thought but surely if no one can see the page then facebook shouldn't be trying to send that url. I added <meta property="og:url" content="MYURL"> the href in the send button looks fine but the pop up contains a URL that is for the object ie, app.facebook.com/pages/mytitle/OGID is that normal?

Comment: @JonDay Getting a little confused, it is sending the generated page? And your app is a canvas app?

Comment: Solved, when you are logged in as an admin of the canvas app the send button will stop working as it tries to use the admin url of the generated page. Thanks for the help and info